# returning null value while fetching record from core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

HI friends when i fetch the records from core data .it showing null . i don't know what is the problem.i am very much happy if any body solves my problem.here is my code.

NOTE: i returned all the core data functions in separate file called 'dbmanager'

```
dbmanager.m

- (NSArray *)fetchAllAds {
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ad" 
inManagedObjectContext:dbManager.managedObjectContext]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; 
return results;
}

- (Ad*)addToFavourite:(NSNumber*)adId text:(NSString*)text type:(LinkupType)type {

Ad *item = (Ad*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ad" 
inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 
item.adId = adId;
item.data =text;
item.state = [NSNumber numberWithInt:type];
[self save];
return item;  
}

- (void)save {
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error7 %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
}

MYviewcontroller.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
self.fetchedRecordsArray = [[DBManager instance]fetchAllAds];
[[DBManager instance]managedObjectContext];
[self.shoppingtbl reloadData];
//NSLog(@"the fetched data is %@",[[DBManager instance]fetchAllAds]);
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.fetchedRecordsArray count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShoppingCart";
ShoppingCart *cell = (ShoppingCart*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
ad=[self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.addesc.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ad.data];
cell.adId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (long)[ad.adId integerValue]];
cell.adstatus.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ad.state];
return cell;
```

}

please try to solve my problem.when i check in nslog it shows like this:

```
     "<Ad: 0x9751570> (entity: Ad; id: 0x974c6b0 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-403A804DFDFB/Ad/p56> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ad: 0x974e370> (entity: Ad; id: 0x9751af0 <x-coredata://B3AA111F-8307-4A16-B898-403A804DFDFB/Ad/p57> ; data: <fault>)"

note:  status section is showing properly!
```

Comment: Your NSLog above shows that you have two objects.  What is shown if you log the properties of these objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSFetchedResultsController instead of using your fetchedRecordsArray array with separate fetch. it is not thread safe to keep ManagedObjects through the code.

Comment: When i create a new manage object request like this-           NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: how to implement for table view cell?

Comment: use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361651/ios-uitableview-sections-with-fetchedresultscontroller-confusion

Comment: no man it not works..still it showing null in id and desc section.status section only works.